# Mercurial - compare local and remote repositories?

Tags: mercurial

In Git, there is the command

```
git remote show <remote>
```

When properly configured, this will show you the status of the remote compared to your local repository, including whether there are pending changes in either. I can't find a similar command in Mercurial. Am I missing something or does it just not exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps [`hg summary --remote`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/summary)?

Comment: Perfect. 7 minutes til I can accept the answer. Arbitrary rule is arbitrary.

Comment: Note that this only works with a `default` remote. You cannot compare against a named remote.

Answer (score 0):

To compare local and remote repositories follow these steps:

1. go to local repo folder (use cd path_to_local_repo)
2. run "hg outgoing -p path_to_remote_repo" (without quotes)

See [GenerateDiffBetweenRepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GenerateDiffBetweenRepositories)