# How do I compare the state of remote Mercurial repositories?

Tags: mercurial

I have a repo forked on BitBucket:

```
$ hg paths
default = https://bitbucket.org/mine/project
upstream = https://bitbucket.org/theirs/project
```

Now I want to compare the (local) state of my repo with its upstream.  Using git I'd just write `git diff --stat upstream/master origin/master` but hg doesn't appear to accept remote branch names as an argument:

```
$ hg diff --stat upstream/default default/default
default/default: No such file or directory
upstream/default: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing I could probably specify it as a [revset](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets), but I'm having trouble getting the syntax right and can't find any examples.

The question [Mercurial - compare local and remote repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877748/mercurial-compare-local-and-remote-repositories) appears related but that just shows the differences between local and remote state; I want to see the difference between remote state and the upstream remote it is forked from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to do it using revsets, although it still feels excessively complicated:

```
$ hg diff -r "remote('.', 'upstream') - remote('.', 'default')"
```

And to generate patches:

```
$ hg export -v -g -r "remote('.', 'default') - remote('.', 'upstream')" -o %r-%m.patch
```

Answer (score 3):

> The question Mercurial - compare local and remote repositories?
>   appears related but that just shows the differences between local and
>   remote state; I want to see the difference between remote state and
>   the upstream remote it is forked from.

Mercurial doesn't include local-remote state.  It has local state and remote state, but not local memory of what the remote last looked like.  For 99% of uses you'll find `hg incoming upstream` and `hg outgoing upstream` tell you what you'd get if you did a push or pull, which is the general form of the question.

If you're using bookmarks as branches in Mercurial (the Mercurial feature bookmark is the closest analog to a git branch) then you can add `--bookmarks` to the `incoming` and `outgoing` lines and the output will tell you how your local `featurebranchbookmark` differs from remote `featurebranchbookmark`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested in mentioned question  `hg summary --remote` in the form  `hg summary --remote -R UPSTREAM-BUNDLE`?

Because:

> With the --remote option, this will check the default paths for incoming and outgoing changes

i.e you can use against upstream, upstream data must be already local somehow

> -R    --repository REPO   repository root directory or **name of overlay bundle file**

and you can spoof command with bundle (result of `hg incoming ... --bundle ) instead of repository

**PS**: 2 pulls from both remotes and diff for two heads can be faster way

Comment: `hg summary --remote -R upstream` just gives `abort: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/theirs/project' is not local`

Comment: @ecatmur - save bundle from upstream under unrelated to path-alias name

Comment: Is that really necessary? Mercurial already knows what's in the upstream remote e.g. I can specify it using the hash of the revision; I just want to know how to refer to it by path alias.